# Moss2007 working with drop down, show textboxes when option is selected

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007

Currently working moss 2007, and having a issue with drop down. If a 3rd option in a drop down is selected then it should show three text boxes below. I know it has to be work with Jquery, but quite new to the jquery. So if any one could provide me code to above issue would be helpful!

Regards
SP.Developer

Comment: Well code examples would be nice just explaining the problem does not accomplish anything without an example of code.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    if($(this).find("option:eq(2)").is(":selected")) {
        $(".theTextBoxes").show();
    } else {
        $(".theTextBoxes").hide();
    }
}).change();
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/34aDs/)

Shorter way:

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    $(".theTextBoxes").toggle($(this).find("option:eq(2)").is(":selected"));
}).change();
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/34aDs/1/)

Comment: That was fast and helpful,
Coming to code how, does the code know to select those textboxes if there are bunch of textboxes in the form?

Comment: @user744324 - selecting the textboxes really depends on the structure of your markup. In the above example I assigned them the class 'theTextBoxes' which simplifies matters somewhat. If you posted your markup it would make things easier.

Comment: I would like to provide the markup, being newbie to sharepoint i couldnt able to figure out the markup for the structure. any help is much appreciated.